# android mapview doesn't display markers after back press

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a mapview in a fragment and after I go to another fragment and press back button it navigates me to the same screen but the map doesn't have markers and camera does not update

**IN ON VIEW CREATED** 
mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.store_map) ;
        mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState) ;

```
    map = mapView.getMap() ;
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-28.362402,24.587402) , 5.0f)  ;
    map.animateCamera(cameraUpdate) ;
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false) ;

    Marker tmpStore;
    LatLng pos;

    BitmapDescriptor bitmapDescriptor = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_map_pin);

            for(int b=0;b<5;b++)
            {

                try
                {
                    pos = new LatLng(Float.parseFloat(storesForMap.get(b).getLatitude()), Float.parseFloat(storesForMap.get(b).getLongitude()));
                    tmpStore = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                            .position(pos)
                            .title(storesForMap.get(b).getRetailer().getName())
                            .icon(bitmapDescriptor)
                            .snippet(storesForMap.get(b).getAddress()));
                    stores.add(tmpStore);

                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.v("STORE_SIZE", "add stores exception: " + e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Log.v("STORE_SIZE", "stores " + stores.size());
            new getTime().execute();

            map.moveCamera( CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-33.9652825, 18.8397661) , 12.0f) );


    }
```

**IN MY XML I HAVE**

```
    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:layout_below="@+id/llTextView"
    android:id="@+id/store_map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with your lifecycle and where you are actually adding the markers.

You are adding them in OnCreate, move that logic to OnResume.

When you go to another fragment and come back from it, OnCreate isn't called again but onResume.

Answer (score 0):

it needs to only to press zoom buttons [+]/[-], the markers are loaded, but not shown